# Fourier multiplier on $L^1$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplier_(Fourier_analysis)#Boundedness_on_L1_or_L%E2%88%9E),
one can read that an iff condition for L1 boundedness of the Fourier multiplier m(D) is that
$$
\hat m\quad\text{ is a Borel measure with finite total mass. }
$$
There is no reference. Is that true ?

Comment: Yes, it is -- for a reference see e.g. the book by Grafakos, "Classical Fourier Analysis", subsection 2.5.4.

Comment: Thanks. I unfortunately started my search by Grafakos "Modern Fourier Analysis".